# Adding Ionic React to an existing React project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-react

Using [this](https://dev.to/ionic/adding-ionic-react-to-an-existing-react-project-4kib) link, I have successfully add the most basic code in my existing react project.
What I'm confused about now is what to do next? How do I create apps out of my existing react project? I guess, I'll need to make this project an Ionic project. But how do I do that?

This is what I have done until now according to the tutorial. The React app runs fine on my web browser.

```
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';
import '@fake-db';
import FuseAuthorization from '@fuse/core/FuseAuthorization';
import FuseLayout from '@fuse/core/FuseLayout';
import FuseTheme from '@fuse/core/FuseTheme';
import history from '@history';
import { createGenerateClassName, jssPreset, StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import { create } from 'jss';
import jssExtend from 'jss-plugin-extend';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import React from 'react';
import Provider from 'react-redux/es/components/Provider';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';
import AppContext from './AppContext';
import { Auth } from './auth';
import routes from './fuse-configs/routesConfig';
import store from './store';

const jss = create({
    ...jssPreset(),
    plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, jssExtend(), rtl()],
    insertionPoint: document.getElementById('jss-insertion-point')
});

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <IonApp>
            <IonReactRouter>
                <IonRouterOutlet>
                    <AppContext.Provider
                        value={{
                            routes
                        }}
                    >
                        <StylesProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                            <Provider store={store}>
                                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
                                    <Auth>
                                        <Router history={history}>
                                            <FuseAuthorization>
                                                <FuseTheme>
                                                    <FuseLayout/>
                                                </FuseTheme>
                                            </FuseAuthorization>
                                        </Router>
                                    </Auth>
                                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                            </Provider>
                        </StylesProvider>
                    </AppContext.Provider>
                </IonRouterOutlet>
            </IonReactRouter>
        </IonApp>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the way to do it.

You'll need something called as the **Ionic Capacitor** to do this. More info. can be found [here](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/).

There's an official article provided by Ionic that can be found [here](https://dev.to/ionic/adding-ionic-react-to-an-existing-react-project-4kib). However, it ***does not*** explain the part that needs to be done to ***generate cross platform apps***.

***Note:*** The above mentioned part ***isn't mandatory*** if you want to ***just*** ***test out*** your React App and see how the actual **Android/iOS/Electron** app is created using Ionic.

If you just want to build cross platform apps without changing any code in your existing react project, then follow the steps provided on [this](https://medium.com/enappd/how-to-make-ionic-apps-in-react-using-capacitor-53f24489889b) page. Scroll down to **Building android app** section.